# What are the disadvantages of using steroids or enhancing drugs while training?

Tags: workout, supplements, athletic-performance

What would you say to a teenager about the use of enhancing drugs apart from the medical conditions that could arise from use?

Comment: No looking at negative impacts in performance (short or long-term).

Comment: That's going to be a stretch, because unfortunately, steroids work.

Comment: @JohnP that's why I asked it.  They work for muscular gains.  I don't have a rapsheet of disadvantages but I could name a couple.  I am sure with a community there will be more insight.

Comment: In that case I'd vote to close it as a list question, as the disadvantages of steroids for teens/adults is well known, and your question doesn't ask about that, it asks specifically for items not related to the medical conditions.

Comment: One example is long-cycling while deadlifting/squatting heavily definitely results in great chance for knee injury.

Comment: All the enhancements in the world will not compare to the results an athlete will produce by hard work and dedication. These enhancements are all short cuts that have no future path.

Setting yourself up mentally and focusing on the goal(s) will make the difference.

Comment: @jasonflaherty - Unfortunately, that is not the case, although it's almost impossible to prove. Nobody knows how good Alex Rodriguez, for example, would have been without drugs. Same for other "legendary" athletes, Lance Armstrong, Lyle Alzado, etc.

Comment: @JohnP - great example Alex Rodriguez - one of many players to be known users to have hip issues.  Maybe he hit 20% less HRs a year but hit HRs for 7 more years right?  Take that close vote away!!!

Comment: @DMoore - Prove that the hip issues are related to drugs and not the natural effects of the sport? Compare that to golf, where many many older golfers have back issues related to the mechanics of the swing itself.

Comment: I'm in chat, hit me up there rather than extending the comment chain.

Comment: Sorry chat doesn't work behind our proxy - blocked.  I am not asking for hard medical studies.  Anecdotal or common relationships is great too.  Would like to be able to point to things that teenagers might care about.  They know that steroids aren't safe - some will not use for these reasons.  I think if I had enough examples of performance issues that I might sway some others.

Comment: In the current form I vote to close as duplicate. Please edit your question to make the distinction to the other question clear.

Comment: By the way: If they want muscular gains, ask them why. If their answer is remotely close to "impress girls", then tell them about how steroids will negatively impact their 'performance' in that field.

Comment: @Informaficker - you and John both had great examples of an answer and you are both voting to close?

Comment: @DMoore Currently the question is a duplicate of the linked question. You can't expect someone to dig through all the comments before writing an answer. I am not sure if I were happy with the question after an edit, though (I agree with JohnP here; list style question). I think it might be best to put it on hold anyway and discuss it on [meta], before reopening.